# Considering German Residence Permit Types

Tags: germany, resident-permit, us-citizens, residence-cards

I am an American citizen intending to relocate with my German partner (unmarried) to Germany in a few months' time. We have been told unequivocally I can only have one of three permit types (an employment permit, job seeker, student/language course).

I can move there for 90 days without a visa and secure the permit during that time.  I do not currently speak German, so I want to learn German and seek employment. I'm unclear on the ability to seek work while on a language visa, so I want to figure out what is the best combination of visas to get me the longest amount of time to learn German and secure a job (I have a PhD in social policy and previous work experience. I did get second place in a job recently without any German, so I feel that with German I could secure employment).

Can I either a) secure a language permit that allows me to look for work and then change to an employment permit or b) use a language permit until I'm done and then change to a job seeker's permit? Or should I just try to learn enough German in the 90 days and secure a job seeker's permit?

Thoughts on the best course of action would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you determine if you PhD is listed in the *ANABIN* Database. (I have no info how this can be done) Can you (in the worst case scenario) support yourself fo upto 6 months while looking for a job?

Comment: Yes, it is in the database (it is also from a European university, as I mentioned, I'm not concerned about my qualifications to secure a job). Yes, I would be able to support myself for the 6 months of job searching. I'm just concerned about reaching a standard of German needed in the time frame, which is why i'm considering the language visa to extend my time to learn the language.

Comment: Yes, but is important since it is pre condition for may visa types (Job seeker, Blue Card). Will look into the details of language visa later [but short of time at the moment] and the combinations possible. Will post answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your conditions:

- US Citizen who can apply for a visa from inside Germany
- has a **ANABIN** reconised degree
- needs an Instensiv language course for profession

The combination:

- 90 day visa free to search for a course, flat etc.
- §16b (2) AufenthG: Study visa up to 12 months (10 per week work allowed)
- Job-Seeker-Visa (§18c AufenthG), 6 months without work and when found

  - Blue Card application

would seem to me the best combination.

Comment: Thanks very much for your thoughts and consideration. I'm a bit unclear on the second-second bullet. 
What is the "§16b (2) AufenthG: Study visa up to 12 months (10 per week work allowed)" exactly? 
Is that 12 months to study a language course which also allows part-time work? Would I have to leave Germany to apply for the Job-Seeker visa after the language course or would I be able to apply for the Job-Seeker visa while in Germany and remain there when I am finished with the language training?

Comment: As a US-Citizen you can apply within Germany. §16b (1)  is for Sprachkurs (Language course). §16b (2) : if the course serves to complete a professional education, work up to 10 hours a week is allowed. One visa leads to the next with the goal of achieving the last.